# Difference between offline rendering and real time rendering

Tags: graphics, three.js, webgl, render, blender

I have a model that I am trying to use in a web game using three.js.

When I render an image of the scene in blender, the quality of the image is very good. Specifically, the quality of the textures is very high and they are very crisp and matte.

When I setup the scene in my game, they look very dull and almost plain.

I've looked up Raytracing, Ambient occlusion, lightmaps. But all of these effect the lighting. They should not affect the quality of the textures. What am I missing here?

What all does blender's offline renderer do that real time renderers (like threejs's webgl render) usually don't do?

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at mipmapping?

Answer (score 0):

Merry Christmas,

i guess the best way is to use baking... That means you save the high qualitiy lightning information into an image texture. (This should solve your problem with plain looking textures)

I recommend to check out this tutorial by Andrew Price(blenderguru.com):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU

And make sure your realtime client uses a proper texture filtering, has support for normalmaps
etc and that the webclient does not downscale your images for some reason.